# What is an appropriate observation / data points in time-series forecasting?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, dataset

I am doing time-series forecasting on data from FRED. Although, as it is possible to select the time frame and frequency I am not sure how many observations I should pick.

For instance, is 35 quarterly observations (9 years approx) sufficient for a time-series analysis / forecasting? I know that for regression, it is preferable to have as many observations as possible. But since I would like to avoid currecnt COVID-19- and the financial crisis impact I have left those out.

Should I include more observations or would the 35 observations be considered sufficient?

Comment: It's your choice. Just make it clear what is and is not included in the data. That said, it would help if you were to say more about the analysis, e.g., what are you predicting? What forecasting method are you using? The latter issue is particularly important as some methods are greedier wrt the length of the series, e.g., ARIMAs in the case where seasonality is to be expressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many observations you need depends on what model you are using. For most parametric models rule of thumb is to have at least about 25-30 observations per independent coefficient in the model.

In addition, in order to test how good your forecasting model is, you would normally want to test its accuracy out of the sample. For that you would split your sample into training set and testing set (typically 75% of data would be assigned to training and rest to testing sample). Hence, for forecasting you would want to have more data in order to be able to do this.

Lastly, generally speaking, more data is always better for accuracy. However, as pointed out in the comments, this is conditional on that more data coming from the same data generating process (DGP). Structural changes in economy can change the DGP so it might be appropriate to restrict your dataset in such cases. Nonetheless, the above still holds.

Comment: More data *from the same data generating process (DGP)* is better for accuracy. But DGPs in areas like macroeconomics and finance tend to evolve over time, so samples spanning longer time periods risk having the DGP at the beginning being quite different from the DGP at the end.

Comment: @RichardHardy thanks for that caveat I fully agree, that’s why I also said generally, but I agree it’s better to spell it out I edited my answer to reflect that

Comment: Thanks, looks great now.

Comment: The rule of thumb I have heard is at least 48 data points. But I would think this would vary depending on if the data is months, years, etc. I always thought of the 48 point minimum as a pseudo power issue. One has to be careful about structural breaks and having enough data to deal with seasonality if it exists.